# How to factory reset non-colored IKEA Trådfri bulbs?

Tags: smart-home, smart-lights, ikea-tradfri

I have a couple of dimmable, but non-colored, [IKEA lights](https://www.ikea.com/se/sv/p/tradfri-led-ljuskaella-e27-1000-lumen-tradloes-dimbar-varmvit-globformad-opalvit-60338452/). I have learned that the proper way to factory reset them is to turn them off and on again 6 times quickly. That worked for Trådfri lights I had of a different model.

However, when I do this to these non-colored lights, they don't reset. I noticed that they don't seem to go out fully if I do it too quickly (unlike the other models), but neither waiting for them to light up and dim out fully nor ignoring that and just doing it quickly worked. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Mozilla IoT wiki](https://github.com/mozilla-iot/wiki/wiki/HOWTO:-Factory-reset-an-IKEA-bulb) made note of this exact problem.

> If you have problems resetting the plain white (non-colour) IKEA bulb, try making the "ons" very brief (less than a second) and the "offs" longer

This solution worked well for me, and I was able to reset them without much trouble after trying it.